# Tracing the addresses of pointers in Debugger

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code:

```
    void WriteToConsole(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *ntHeader)
    {
    std::cout << "AddressOfEntryPoint = " <<
        ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint << std::endl;
    }
    void main()
    {
    //something
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *NtHeader = GetWinNTHeader(dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    WriteToConsole(NtHeader);
    }
```

Why do the addresses of NtHeader and ntHeader differ? 
I am tracing the addresses using a debugger.

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * GetWinNTHeader(long offset)
{
    // IMAGE_NT_HEADERS size is 120
    char buffer[120];
    file.seekg(offset);
    file.read(buffer, 120);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(buffer);
    if (IsBadReadPtr(pHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)))
        return NULL;
    if (pHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;
    return pHeader;
}
```

Comment: you are creating a pointer, initialising it and then printing it for the first time inside that function...so, how do you know that it has changed??

Comment: main () should return int. An optimising compiler is likely to forget the value of NTHeader because it isn't needed after the call. Try to print it out before and after the call, and it will be the same.

Comment: Your code is OK but `OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint` is not same as `NtHeader`.

Comment: Where is the proof it changed? What changes? The address of the variable `ntHeader` or the value of  `ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint`?

Comment: I know that it changes then i'm using debug. After cout call, value of NTHeader was changed.

Comment: Please show us the `GetWinNTHeader` function.  It is doing something obviously wrong or ill-advised.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using some debugger to see the value of NtHeader.
The value "changes" since it's allocated on the stack and after you called WriteToConsole you leave its scope which leads to the deallocation of NtHeader.

EDIT:

The fact that NtHeader is allocated in main() makes this question somewhat pointless because why would you care about a variables value if the program is about to exit anyway?

Comment: And what I need to do?

Comment: change its scope if you want to use it afterwards

Comment: Can I do this, than i dont make NTHeader is global?

Comment: I just realized that its your main function NTHeader is allocated in. So I don't think you can do much about it.

Comment: have you tried passing pointer  by reference??IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *& ntHeader

Comment: @EXTRAM - Show us the GetWinNTHeadert function, so that you get optimal / good answers, and not guesses.

Comment: @basav no. What that can gives me?

Comment: If you pass it by reference, then essentially you are passing the address of pointer...so, if you are checking the addresses in debugger, they should match .

Comment: @basav I change GetWinNTHeader(*) to GetWinNTHeader(*&). How i need to change function call for this?

Comment: pls check the code below.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for I think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

 void WriteToConsole(char *&ntHeader)
    {
    std::cout << "AddressOfEntryPoint = " <<
       &ntHeader  << std::endl;
    }


int main()
{

    //something
    char *NtHeader = "hello";
std::cout << "AddressOfEntryPoint = " <<
       &NtHeader  << std::endl;
    WriteToConsole(NtHeader);

return 0;
}
```

output:
**AddressOfEntryPoint = 0x7fff7a90b168
AddressOfEntryPoint = 0x7fff7a90b168**

Now if you change it to pass by pointer,

```
void WriteToConsole(char *ntHeader)
```

adn call it this way,  `WriteToConsole(NtHeader);`,

Then you get the differing addresses.
**AddressOfEntryPoint = 0x7fffae028ca8
AddressOfEntryPoint = 0x7fffae028c88**

If you donot want to create a copy and want the same adddress you always pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue, regardless of what your function is attempting to do , is that you're returning the address of a local variable.  That is undefined behavior.

Basically, you are doing this:

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * GetWinNTHeader(long offset)
{
    // IMAGE_NT_HEADERS size is 120
    char buffer[120];
    //...
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(buffer);
    //...
    return pHeader;  
}
```

Since `pHeader` is an alias for `buffer`, you are returning the address of a local variable, `buffer`.

The solution is basically -- `don't do this`.  Never return a reference or pointer to a local variable.

Here is one solution, using a struct:

```
struct HeaderBuffer
{
   char buffer[120];
};

HeaderBuffer GetWinNTHeader(long offset)
{
    // IMAGE_NT_HEADERS size is 120
    HeaderBuffer hBuffer;
    file.seekg(offset);
    file.read(hBuffer.buffer, 120);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(hBuffer.buffer);
    if (IsBadReadPtr(pHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)))
        hBuffer.buffer[0] = 0;
    else
    if (pHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
       hBuffer.buffer[0] = 0;
    return hBuffer;
}

 void WriteToConsole(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *ntHeader)
 {
    std::cout << "AddressOfEntryPoint = " <<
        ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint << std::endl;
 }
```

The caller would look something like this:

```
 int main()
 {
    HeaderBuffer buf = GetWinNTHeader(dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *NtHeader = static_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*>(buf.buffer);
    WriteToConsole(NtHeader);
 }
```

Note:  This has not been compiled, so be aware of this.

Basically, the function returns a char buffer wrapped within a struct. Instead of returning `NULL`, we return a buffer that has no information (the char buffer has `strlen` of 0).